# Как в Wordpress задать строгий размер изображения?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Вывожу изображение через стандартный Фото блок. В настройках блока есть "Enter image size (Example: "thumbnail", "medium", "large", "full" or other sizes defined by theme). Alternatively enter size in pixels (Example: 200x100 (Width x Height))."
Хочу сделать так, чтобы изображение не ресайзилось более 100%, чтобы не страдала четкость и резкость. Если пробую указывать заданные размеры высоты и ширины, вордпресс это игнорирует и все равно ресайзит изображение. Подскажите, как задать строгий размер изображения или запретить его ресайз более 100%

Comment: Может быть простыми css стилями?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы добавить новый размер можете использовать ф-нкцию [add_image_size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/), последний аргумент отвечает за то, чтобы обрезать картинку строго по размерам.

**Важно:** после изменения размеров изображений, их нужно нарезать заново. Например использовав плагин [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/).

Например твоя картинка имеет размер 500х500:

- `add_image_size( 'your-image-size', '150', '430' );` - изображение будет 430х430
- `add_image_size( 'your-image-size', '150', '430', true );` - изображение будет 150х430 взяв за основу центр изображения и обрежет края
- `add_image_size( 'your-image-size', '150', '430', [ 'top', 'right' ] );` - изображение будет 150х430 взяв за основу правый верхний угол изображения и обрежет все остальное.

Если вы хотите обновить стандартный тип, то можно изменить его через настройки. Пример:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'modify_theme_image_sizes' );
function modify_theme_image_sizes() {

    // Изменить размер medium 
    update_option( 'medium_size_w', 360 );
    update_option( 'medium_size_h', 240 );
    update_option( 'medium_crop', 1 );

    add_image_size( 'your-image-size', '150', '430', true );
}
```